# how can i implemented cloud computing in my application?

Tags: android

i have a problem that i am using web services and want that for example i have implemented facebook in my application and want that all the notification that arise in my facebook will get notified in my android phone even if application is installed but not opened in phone. So, to implement this into my application i think i have to use cloud computing but how can i do this i dont know. Can anyone help me out of this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of application you have already written, but you need the implement a backend that checks the Facebook notifications, which can (probably) be done using the Facebook API: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/291

To send the notifications to the phone, you can use push notifications. Since 2.2 this can be done with Cloud To Device Messaging:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html
and
http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/