# how to create push notification in android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am developing android application that would receive data from server any time.i have searched in google to get some information.

1)android cloud to device messaging(C2DM).
2)persistent TCP/IP connection.

how to implement C2DM function and other one how to register C2DM?.please explain detail and send me sample application

Comment: Following Answer will help you.

[Cloud Messaging android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310907/how-can-i-implemented-cloud-computing-in-my-application

Comment: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using C2DM will continue to work https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

Answer (score 3):

C2DM is deprecated and you can use GCM for your requirement

Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their Android applications on Android devices. This could be a lightweight message telling the Android application that there is new data to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly). The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to the target Android application running on the target device

This document describes how to write an Android application and the server-side logic, using the helper libraries (client and server) provided by GCM.

Check these links,

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/19226-android-push-notification-gcm-framework-tutorial.html

http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/

for client side app you can find the code here

https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Answer (score 0):

c2dm is deprecated.

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm

Maybe you'd better start with GCM

best regards